# Working on json feed with python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm trying to automate some tasks using python, and the first among them is
to create a db entry out of a large json feed.

My json looks more or less like that (the list was shorten for this example):

```
{
    "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "AFN": "Afghan Afghani"
}
```

The relevant parts of the code is:

```
page = requests.get('http://LINK-TO-JSON-FEED')
print page.json()
items = page.json()
for item in items:
    print item
```

but this only printed out the "ISO" (AED, AFN.. ) without the "String" (United Arab Emirates Dirham... ) part.

i'm looking to eventually print them within a loop in the their original pairs, something like

```
Print ISO // AED
Print STRING // United Arab Emirates Dirham
```

Comment: What do you mean by ISO? Take this for instance >>> "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham" ... which part are you referring to?

Comment: I'm thinking something like 'AED'. Still, the description failed to explain itself.  Some code might be helpful

Comment: @skyline75489 Sorry about that, you actually got it right. anyway, i've edited the question so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items` is a dictionary. If you iterate over a dictionary, then by definition, you iterate over the *keys*  of the dictionary.

If (as in your example) you want to [iterate over both keys and values](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques), you need to use `.items()` (Python 3) oder `.iteritems()` (Python 2):

```
for key, value in items.iteritems():
    print "{}:\t{}".format(key, value)
```